# How to put a block in the top part of a column?

Tags: beamer, columns, block

How can I put a block in the top part of a column in beamer?

For example I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            Left column
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Block 1}
                Text of the block
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I insert the option `[t]` to `frame` it moves up also the content of the left column.

**How can I put the block in the top part of its column?**

Answer (score 0):

beamer columns are  basically just glorified minipages. If you directly use minipages, you can control their height and vertical position:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

        \begin{minipage}[c][.8\textheight][c]{0.5\textwidth}
            Left column
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[c][.8\textheight][t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Block 1}
                Text of the block
            \end{block}
        \end{minipage}%
            

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]